# How to change resize imageview in titleview - SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I would like to load an image to the titleview and then change the size.

I'm using this code :

```
   let logo = UIImage(named: "namelogo")
   let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:70, height:30))
   imageView.image = logo
   self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

But this is not working properly. I can play with the height, but the width is not changing !!!

Comment: Try using .contentMode property. Try setting it .scaleToFill

Comment: Tried ! this is not working

Comment: you need to cut image to display size, for example nav bar height = 44, thats means imageHeight = 88 and 132 for 3x displays

Comment: @YasserB. I check your code its working fine for my images. can you send me your "namelogo" image

Comment: Here is the namelogo https://athenaassets.s3.amazonaws.com/db76e84c84a51a75633385f160d2bf08_namelogo.png